# BeautifulSoup returns an empty div, but it's not empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with BeautifulSoup in Python. I am trying to scrape a website and find a scpecific div,but the div is being returned without any content. Let me show you:

This is the code:

```
dev make_soup(url):
   headers = {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4)AppleWebKit/537.36"
   }
   try:
      html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
   excpet:
      return None
   return BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
   

   
soup = make_soup(https://www.nike.com/de/t/air-jordan-1-low-se-damenschuh-RxZs2k/DO0750-002)

form = soup.find("form", {"id": "buyTools"})
div = form.find("div")
print(div)
```

Here is what it prints:

```
<div class="pr16-sm pr10-lg"></div>
```

Here is what it is supposed to ptint (not formatted like this of course):

```
<div class="pr16-sm pr10-lg">
   <fieldset class="mt5-sm mb3-sm body-2 css-1pj6y87">...</fieldset>
</div>
```

I have tried to find the fieldset from the whole soup object, find all fieldsets etc. nothing works. I also cannot find anything on the internet.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Edit:
This is the actual html code, beginning from the form which it does find.

```
<form id="buyTools" class="add-to-cart-form nike-buying-tools">
   <div class="pr16-sm pr10-lg">
      <fieldset class="mt5-sm mb3-sm body-2 css-1pj6y87">
         <legend class="...">...</legend>
         <div class="mt2-sm css-12whm6">[THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO FIND]</div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Without the actual HTML, this is hard to debug. For all we know, there are two div elements with that specific class.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put that. I'll edit it right in!

Comment: Edited. Like I said, it finds the form and the first child div, but this is returned empty, which it obviously isnt.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the html given. I obtain the div and its children.

Comment: Hm. With my code?

Comment: Then I guess it must be a problem with the requests.get() that it doesnt include it there for some reason

Comment: Yes, just the last 3 lines: `form = ...`, `div = ...`, `print(div)`. With `soup = BeautifulSoup(text)`, and `text` your HTML sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239613/discussion-between-rexylp-and-9769953).

Comment: i don't see any form in the link you provided

Answer (score -1):

#### What happens?

1. This product is not available, so you wont find a `form` in developer tools nor in your soup

**EDIT** *Was not available in moment of testing, but that do not change anything, concerning with #2*

2. Website deals with dynamic served content, you could not handle with `requests` cause it do not render the page like a browser.

#### How to fix?

Use `selenium` to get the rendered `html` and process it with `beautiful soup`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

[x.text for x in soup.select('#buyTools fieldset label')]
```

#### Example ([uses selenium 4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_browser_drivers/))

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = ChromeService(executable_path='YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER EXE')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/de/t/air-jordan-1-mid-se-schuh-MkNjwX/DC7294-600')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

[x.text for x in soup.select('#buyTools fieldset label')]

...
```

#### Output

```
['EU 40',
 'EU 40.5',
 'EU 41',
 'EU 42',
 'EU 42.5',
 'EU 43',
 'EU 44',
 'EU 44.5',
 'EU 45',
 'EU 45.5',
 'EU 46',
 'EU 47',
 'EU 47.5',
 'EU 48.5',
 'EU 49.5',
 'EU 50.5']
```